# react native victorychart show tooltip always

Tags: javascript, react-native, victory-charts

I have a victory chart working fine but need the tooltip to show always not only on touch...

```
<VictoryChart
  height={200}
  animate={{ duration: 500 }}
  // domain={{  y: [400000, 498542.15] }}
  containerComponent={
    <VictoryVoronoiContainer
      labels={() => "placeHolder"}
      labelComponent={
        <VictoryTooltip
          style={{ fontSize: "15px", fill: BRAND_COLORS.white }}
          cornerRadius={15}
          pointerLength={10}
          active={true}
          flyoutStyle={{
            stroke: BRAND_COLORS.transparent,
            fill: "red",
          }}
          text={"$345,000.34"}
        />
      }
    />
  }
/>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this in editable source & live preview [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-tooltip/). If `active={true}`, the tooltips are active.

Answer (score 0):

In VictoryChart component add the prop

```
events={[{
            target: 'parent',
            eventHandlers: {
              onTouchEnd: () => {},
            },
          },
        ]}
```